# removing whitespaces from a QRegExpValidator

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a code someone wrote and there

```
 this->llBankCode = new widgetLineEditWithLabel(tr("Bankleitzahl"), "", Qt::AlignTop, this);
 QRegExpValidator *validatorBLZ = new QRegExpValidator(this);
 validatorBLZ->setRegExp(QRegExp( "[0-9]*", Qt::CaseSensitive));
 this->llBankCode->lineEdit->setValidator(validatorBLZ);
```

as it can be seen from this code, is that `validatorBLZ` can accept only numbers between 0 and 9. I would like to change it, that `validatorBLZ` would be able to get as an input whitespace as well (but not to start with a whitespace), but it wont be shown.

Example:
if i try to copy & paste a string of the format '22 34 44', the result would be an empty field. What i would like to happen is that the string '22 34 44' will be shown in the field as '223444'.

How could i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using:

```
QString string = "22 34 44";
string.replace(QString(" "), QString(""));
```

That will replace any spaces with a non-space.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own QValidator subclass and reimplement validate **and** fixup. Fixup does what you ask for: changes the input in a way that makes it intermediate/acceptable.
In your case, consider the following code-snippet for fixup:

```
fixup (QString &input) const
{
  QString fixed;
  fixed.reserve(input.size());
  for (int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    if (input.at(i).isDigit()) fixed.append(input.at(i));
  input = fixed;
}
```

(this is not tested)

The validate function will obviously look similar, returning QValidator::Invalid when it encounters a non-digit character and returning the according position in pos.

If your BLZ is limited to Germany, you could easily add the validation feature that it only returns QValidator::Acceptable when there are eight digits, and QValidator::Intermediate else.

Anyhow, writing an own QValidator, which often is very easy and straight forward, is the best (and most future-proof) solution most of the time. RegExes are great, but C++ clearly is the more powerful language here, which in addition results in a much more readable validator ;).